# Why hasChildNodes returns true for an Empty Node?

Tags: javascript, html

The user should be alerted when he/she clicks purchase and there is nothing in the cart, however, it doesn't respond.
When running the program, it says it cannot read property of addEventListener of undefined. Any way to fix this and the cart problem?

```js
var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
    var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
}

var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
    var input = quantityInputs[i]
    input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
}

var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button')
for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
    var button = addToCartButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
}

document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener("click", purchaseClicked);

function purchaseClicked() { 

    if (document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0].hasChildNodes){
        alert('Thanks!')
    } 
    else {
        alert("There is nothing in your cart!");
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="container content-section">
    <h2 class="heading">CART</h2>
    <div class="cart-row">
        <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
        <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
        <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cart-items">
    </div>
    <div class="cart-total">
        <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
        <span class="cart-total-price">$0</span>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="button">PURCHASE</button>
</section>
```

Comment: `hasChildNodes` is a function, so it should be `hasChildNodes()`.  As the code is above, it's basically saying *"yes, that function exists"* and returning true.

Comment: I changed it to 'hasChildNodes()' and it still seems to not be able to read the propert of addEventListener.

Comment: Is this script running after the page has loaded, or is it as above?  If it's as above then the button doesn't exist when the script is trying to reference it.

Comment: No, the script is running after the page is loaded

Comment: There's something else at work then, that isn't posted here.  I've moved your code into a snippet so you can run it in this page and the *only* thing wrong with it is the fact that it doesn't have empty parenthesis after `hasChildNodes`.

Comment: Would you like to see my full HTML and JavaScript? I used the debugger and it seems it say there is something here.

Comment: No, that wouldn't be relevant.  Your questions should only be a [mcve], not your complete code.  You just need to figure out *why* that element does not exist on the page at the time that you try to attach the event handler, because that's what the problem is.

Comment: Can you please provide which `addEventListener` is causing the error, as there seems to be multiple.

Comment: The button.addEventListener seems to be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 main reasons for your issue

**Reason #1:** 
As discussed in the comments, `hasChildNodes` is a function which means it needs parenthesis after it, i.e. `hasChildNodes()`

**Reason #2:**
For `hasChildNodes()` to return `true`, the caller node must be literally empty. This means it cannot contain anything, even a white space

For example: `<div></div>` has **NO** child nodes, while `<div> </div>` has a child node which is the **white space**.

I edited your code accordingly and it worked (i.e. I added the parenthesis to  `hasChildNodes()` and removed spaces and newlines from withing the div to become `<div class="cart-items"></div>`)

```js
var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
    var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
}

var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
    var input = quantityInputs[i]
    input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
}

var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-button')
for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
    var button = addToCartButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
}

document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener("click", purchaseClicked);

function purchaseClicked() { 

    if (document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0].hasChildNodes()){
        alert('Thanks!')
    } 
    else {
        alert("There is nothing in your cart!");
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<section class="container content-section">
    <h2 class="heading">CART</h2>
    <div class="cart-row">
        <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
        <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
        <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cart-items"></div>
    <div class="cart-total">
        <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
        <span class="cart-total-price">$0</span>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" type="button">PURCHASE</button>
</section> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You did it! Thanks a ton!